# Using 1 as minimum value for a Radar Chart

Tags: d3.js

I'm using a D3.js RadarChart based on this example: https://github.com/alangrafu/radar-chart-d3.

The problem is that my data has a minimum value of 1, so I would like to have the value 1 in the middle of the Radar. But the script assumes that the minimum value is 0.

Is there a way to change that? Thanks for helping out.

Comment: It looks like this would be quite a major change -- the minimum value is never set explicitly, but 0 is assumed throughout the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a little hackish, but it might be easier to modify your input data. From the [example page](http://graves.cl/radar-chart-d3/):

```
d = [
     [
           {axis: "strength", value: 13}, 
           {axis: "intelligence", value: 1}, 
           {axis: "charisma", value: 8},  
           {axis: "dexterity", value: 4},  
           {axis: "luck", value: 9}
          ],[
           {axis: "strength", value: 3}, 
           {axis: "intelligence", value: 15}, 
           {axis: "charisma", value: 4}, 
           {axis: "dexterity", value: 1},  
           {axis: "luck", value: 15}
          ],[
           {axis: "strength", value: 5}, 
           {axis: "intelligence", value: 1}, 
           {axis: "charisma", value: 16}, 
           {axis: "dexterity", value: 10},  
           {axis: "luck", value: 5}
     ]
];
```

To make the plot start at 1 instead of 0, just subtract 1:

```
d.forEach(function(shape){
  shape.forEach(function(attribute){
    attribute.value = attribute.value - 1;
  });
});
```

To do it properly, you'll need to change the [source of the library](https://github.com/alangrafu/radar-chart-d3/blob/master/src/radar-chart.js).

Create a scale:

```
var scale = d3.scale.linear().domain([cfg.minValue, cfg.maxValue])
```

That maps values to [0, 1]. Then, replace all the instances of

```
parseFloat(Math.max(j.value, 0))/cfg.maxValue
```

with

```
scale(parseFloat(Math.max(j.value, 0)))
```

Comment: Thanks Adam. I changed the library (since I changed it anyway to display a legend) and it works fine with your adjustments. Apart from that it helped me understand D3 better. Thanks!